# default route parameters in asp.net mvc RouteConfig

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have RouteConfig

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "EmployerDefault",
          url: "{lang}/employer",
          defaults: new { lang = "ru", controller = "Employer", action = "Index" }
      );
    }
}
```

and  Controller

```
 public class EmployerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("EmployerMaster");
    }
}
```

When i  go to link   **/employer** , i get HTTP 404.0 - Not Found ,
but when i try to get  **/ru/employer** it's OK. 
I want that /employer and /ru/employer links refer to one page. 
Why it's happens ? How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "EmployerDefault",
          url: "/employer",
          defaults: new { lang = "ru", controller = "Employer", action = "Index" }

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "EmployerWithLang",
          url: "{lang}/employer",
          defaults: new { lang = "ru", controller = "Employer", action = "Index" }
      );
    }
}
```